# How can I use an aggregation pipeline to see which documents have a field with a string that starts with any of the strings in a list?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongo server version 3.4, so my question pertains to the functionality of that version.  I cannot upgrade anytime soon, so please keep that in mind.  If have a field in some documents in a MongoDB collection that may contain a string but also have trailing characters, how might I find them when submitting multiple "startsWith" strings to be evaluated in the same query?  I may have some difficulty explaining this, so let me show some examples.  Let's say that I have a field called "description" in all of my documents.  This description might be encoded so that the text is not completely straightforward.  Some values might be:

```
green:A-4_ABC
yellow:C-12_456
red:A-431_ZXCVQ
yellow_green:C-12_999
brown:B-3_R
gray:EN-44_195
```

EDIT: I think I made a mistake with using words in my keys.  The keys are a randomized string of numbers, letters, and underscores, followed by a colon, then one to three letters, followed by a dash, then a couple of numbers, then an underscore, and lastly followed by several alphanumeric characters:

```
LKEF543SLI54EH2J897FQ_HF234EWOH:ZX-82_FR2
```

I realize that this sounds arbitrary and stupid, but it is an encoding of information that is intended to result in a unique key.  It is in data that I receive, so I cannot change it, unfortunately.

Now, I want to find all of the documents with descriptions that start with any of the following values, and all of these values must be submitted in the same query.  I might have hundreds of submitted values, and I need to get all matching documents at once.  Here is a short list of what might be submitted in a single query:

```
green:A-4
red:A-431
gray:EN-44
yellow_green:C-12
```

Note that it was not accidental that the text is everything prior to the *last* underscore.  And, as with one of the examples, there might be more than one underscore.  With my use case, I cannot create a query that hard-codes these strings in the javascript regex format.  And the $in filter does not work with "startsWith" functionality, particularly when you pass in a list of strings (though I am familiar with supplying a list of hard-coded javascript regexes).  Is there any way to use the $in operator where I can take a list of strings that are passed in from the user who wants to run a query like this?  Or is there something equivalent?  The cherry on the top of all of this would be to find a way to project the matching document with the string that it matched (either from the query, or by some substring magic that I cannot seem to figure out).

EDIT: Specifically, when I find each document, I want to be able to project everything from they key up until the LAST underscore, like:

```
LKEF543SLI54EH2J897FQ_HF234EWOH:ZX-82
```

(along with its value)

Thanks in advance for any nudges in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `$objectToArray` to get `{k:field_name, v:field_value}` array. Then we split by `_` token all values and convert to object with `$arrayToObject` operator.

Next step we apply `$match` operator to filter documents and exclude `data` with `$unset`.

**Note:** If your document contains array or subdocuments, we may use `$filter` before we convert `$objectToArray`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: {
              $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
            },
            in: {
              k: "$$this.k",
              v: {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $split: [
                      {
                        $toString: "$$this.v"
                      },
                      "_"
                    ]
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "data.green": "A-4",
      "data.red": "A-431",
      "data.gray": "EN-44",
      "data.yellow_green": "C-12"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "data"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ELJP61rjUk3)

Comment: That you for your awesome and detailed response.  It would be really great, but that's why I mentioned mongo 3.4.  I cannot use arrayToObject, nor objToArray with my version, unfortunately.

Comment: Also, please see my edits.  I realized that I needed to clarify the key format.

Comment: @SteveStorck please add example what you expect (add more examples)